# Not getting all values of scrollTop inside scroll handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrolltop

```
 $(window).scroll(function(){  

         console.log($(window).scrollTop());

     });
```

Gives console output below when scrolled

> 2
>
> list (line 392)
>
> 7
>
> list (line 392)
>
> 12
>
> list (line 392)
>
> 18
>
> list (line 392)
>
> 25

Now why 3,4,6 values are missing ??
If I scroll slowly I can get those values (3,4)  problem is I want to use if condition inside scroll handler function like

```
 $(window).scroll(function(){  

         if($(window).scrollTop() == 3 ) alert('hit');

     });
```

Now the above code sometimes work and sometimes not . How can I make it work everytime ?